# Formatting pattern to numbers in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I do this in a select statement [Oracle DB]:

```
Value in column: 12 ----> Output value: 012
Value in column: 112 ----> Output value: 112
Value in column: 2 ----> Output value: 002
```

Can I use `select to_char`? How do I apply it for this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it's a number, you can use `to_char()` with a suitable [format model](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i34570):

```
select to_char(column_name, '000') from ...
```

Trivial [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/de65c/1).

As a_horse_with_no_name noticed, you'll get a leading space with this format model, to allow for a possible negation symbol. To avoid that, add the [`FM` format modifier](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements004.htm#i170559).

Answer (score 9):

```
select to_char(the_column, 'FM000')
from sample_Data
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/24726

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF51074